# LINQ: Inner join to the First row in a sub query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have two classes, basically one holds Members and the other Sessions.

They are joined together with a common field called "name". There is one member but can be many Sessions.

So if I do a standard join I get back 1 member and many sessions. I just want to get back the first row of sessions.

The session has field called SessioEndTime. So I need to order by DESC on this to pick out the first record.

This is my linq; I have returns too many. I think I need a subquery but I am a little confused.

```
  var sessions = from m in this.members 
                   join s in this.sessions
                   on m.Name equals s.Name
                   select new { MemberName = m.Name, SessionTime = s.SessioEndTime};
```

### Edit

To make it clear, imagine I have five members, each member has NUMEROUS sessions. I just wish to receive my five members but with only one session each, that session is the LATEST session which can be got from the SessioEndTime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sessions =  
    from m in this.members                     
    join s in 
    (
        from se in this.sessions
        group se by se.Name into g
        select new {Name = g.Key, SessioEndTime = g.Max(a=>a.SessioEndTime)}
    )   
    on m.Name equals s.Name                    
    select new { MemberName = m.Name, SessionTime = s.SessioEndTime}
```

Comment: Thanks Cybernate, probably didn't explain it right.. I will update the question... but basically i am looking for Every member with ONly 1 session for each member.. The code you suggested returns only 1 member with the 1 session.. but i have 4 more members in my collection.

Comment: I think i need to have a subquery but i am unsure... so that the join goes against only 1 record which is got from the subquery??

Comment: I love the join into a subquery. I'm continually reminded of the flexibility of LINQ and the fact that queries can be as complex as you need them to be. I'd already given you +1 before your edit, but thanks for reminding me what I can do.